# To prove that in $K[x]$ , where $K=\mathbb Z_{p}(t)$, $f(x)=x^{p} -t $ is irreducible

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

$K=\mathbb Z_{p}(t)$  is  the  field  of  all  rational  polynomials over  $\mathbb Z_{p}$ .

The  polynomial $$f(x)=x^{p} -t $$  has  to  be  irreducible  over  $K[x]$.

So  the  polynomial  is  in $\mathbb Z_{p} (t)[x]$

Now  $f'(x)=0$ so  I  guess  this  polynomial  will  not  be  separable  in   its  splitting  field, shall  have  repeated  roots.

Can  I   arrive  at  a  contradiction  from  here $?$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Much more generally, if $k$ is a completely arbitrary field of any characteristic and $n\geq 1$ an arbitrary integer, then the polynomial  $P=P(x,t)=x^n-t$ is irreducible over $k(t)$.

Indeed $P$ is irreducible in $k[x,t]$ (since it is of degree one in $t$), thus also equivalently in $(k[t])[x]$ and finally also in $k(t)[x]$.
The last step is the crucial one: if A is a UFD (here $A=k[t]$) with fraction field $K=\operatorname {Frac}(A)$, then a non constant polynomial irreducible in $A[x]$ is automatically irreducible in $K[x]$.